# How can I configure proxy authentication?

Tags: 11.10, proxy

The Ubuntu 11.10 has only simple proxy configuration.
Where is the authentication option? 
so it can be used to download packages?

Comment: You could try the easy to use GUI tool [GrrProxy](https://github.com/Cadogan/GrrProxy)

Answer (score 7):

Try specifying the proxy address as `username:password@address`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From reading the [upstream bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646354) about this, it looks to be possible, but requires you to enter the host in the form of `username:password@host` in the network proxy dialog.

Comment: What if the password itself contains "`:`"? Do I need to escape it then?

Answer (score 1):

In system setting network option there you would find proxy option and apply system wide,if this does not work then put firefox it will work.