# how to setup a https proxy

Tags: proxy, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure proxy authentication?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65828/how-can-i-configure-proxy-authentication)

The Ubuntu 11.10 has only simple proxy configuration. Where is the authentication option? 
is there any ***https proxy*** connector apps in ubuntu? I bought an httpS proxy (it requires user name and pass and uses port 808) i used proxifier in windows and mac to connect to it. I realy need this. I need an app for that in ubuntu.i searched alot in google but no luck!
any suggestions